# How can I get tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices to accept my dtype?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dtype

```
# Convert to Tensor
imagepaths = tf.convert_to_tensor(imagepaths, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.int32)
# Build a TF Queue, shuffle data
image, label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([imagepaths, labels])
```

So the following code is what I am using with Tensorflow 2, I keep on changing my types that I convert to however it continuously gives me errors no matter which I use. Any Ideas? Below I have listed some of the errors I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Pack as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a string tensor but is a int32 tensor [Op:Pack] name: component_0


return ops.EagerTensor(value, handle, device, dtype)
TypeError: Cannot convert provided value to EagerTensor
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two tensors into one Dataset object by slicing a tuple of the two tensors.
Like this:

```
# Convert to Tensor
imagepaths = tf.convert_to_tensor(imagepaths, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.int32)
# Build a TF Queue, shuffle data
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imagepaths, labels))
```

Notice that the tensors should have the same size in their first dimension.

Comment: how about if it is dataframe and you need to set each columns dtype ?